# vC: scan numeric input until EOF

Tags: c

I have an assignment, when in C programming language, I have to scan multiple numeric (just integer, if it's not integer, it should exit) values from keyboard. Values are divided by space and input is ended by EOF. I need to further work with these scanned values. I know maximum of putted numbers, I don't know beforehand how many numbers I'll get.

I tried:

```
 while (scanf("%d", &a) == 1 && count <= 10000 )  {
  eof=a;
  if ( eof=getchar() == EOF ) break;
 ...
```

But it doesn't seem to work as I need (often you have to give EOF twice, but not always, and it sometimes adds 0 to the input). Same happens when I use just:

```
while (scanf("%d", &a) == 1) {
```

if I try:

```
 while (... && (a=getchar()) != EOF) {
```

the variable a is rewritten and I can't work with it further.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Furthermore, I need to distinguish between EOF and invalid input (something other than number), which I am not sure how to do, because

```
scanf(...)==1
```

won't do that job.

Comment: Having a `getchar` call in the loop will give you wrong values when calling `Scanf`.

Comment: As for distinguishing between different results from [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), just save its return value in a variable and check it.

Comment: Storing return value from `scanf` in variable and checking it separately is working, it seems like the best solution. Thanks!

Comment: "have to give EOF twice, but not always" is not an issue with your code.  It is a detail of how your terminal accepts input and determines when to signal `EOF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the result of `scanf()` be it `0`, `1`,or `EOF`.

```
int count = 0;
int a;
int scnt;
while ((scnt = scanf("%d", &a) != EOF && count < 10000 )  {  // not <= 10000
  if (scnt == 0) {
    // Handle stdin with unconvertible input. OP wants "it should exit"
    puts("Bad");
    exit (-1);
  } else {
    // Success! Let's print it
    printf("%d %d\n", count++, a);
  }
}
// why did we quit?
if (count >= 10000)
  puts("Too many");
else if (feof(stdin)) {
  puts("EOF detected");
else if (ferror(stdin)) {  // rare
  puts("IO error on detected");
else // Should never occur
  puts("???");
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of scanning for integers, read the whole line at once using e.g. [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), and then get the number from that.

Then you can easily just put the `fgets` call in the loop condition, and don't need any other check.

---

If `fgets` is impractical to use, then how about nested loops, one outer that ends on end-of-file condition (a special flag you set), and an inner that uses e.g. `getchar` to read all characters. If `getchar` returns `EOF` you set the flag for the outer loop and break out of the inner loop.

Of course, this means you have parse and put together the numbers yourself, but unless you have to handle larger numbers that can be handled by the normal standard types then it's trivial.

Comment: This won't work for me, 1) I don't know the length of that string (it can be from 5 to more than 15000 chars), 2) since it's school assignment, the program will run in limited environment.. and I'm not sure if variable that large will be possible in that environment (but I suppose not :/ )

Comment: @Luga Updated answer with another possible solution.